# Print array without item that contains a certain string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

So, if I have code like this:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "null"] 

print a
```

The number of `"null"`s varies in the output quite a lot for some reason.
How could I delete all array elements which are match the `"null"` string before printing?

Comment: So you want to filter out all `"null"`s?

Comment: Try `print a[:len(a) - 1]`.

Comment: Do you want to `print A` or do you want to delete all `"null"`s from `A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to filter your list is using list comprehension:

```
print([x for x in a if x != "null"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through your list to print out everything that does not equal to "null"

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "null"] 

for data in a:
    if data != "null":
        print(data)
```

If you were looking to filter out data you don't want in your data structure, however, then, the easiest way to do this is to do this in a list comprehension that will remove unwanted "null"

```
res = [data for data in a if data != "null"]
```

Comment: What if I have a function, like def strA(A):

Comment: Apparetnly I cant put lines... def str(A): aSTR = ", ".join(A)?

Comment: @m1ksu I don't understand what you are asking exactly? Are you saying that the function returns a list?

Comment: @idjaw I have a list where items can be added and removed from when you call the function. This can take multiple arguments. But, I have a lot of arguments. If I don't need them, I set them to "null". I have code that doesn't add "null" to the function. But, now that I use the *add (add is my argument which adds an item to the list) instead of add, it puts a couple "null"s in the output. The output should be only the list without special marks and such.

Comment: @m1ksu This is information that should have been in your question from the beginning. Your question was simply how to print a list ignoring items in the list. There is a solution that also shows how to filter the list out for unwanted items. Beyond that, are you looking to simply ignore even putting invalid items from the beginning? Are you looking to put that in to a method?

Answer (score 0):

@m1ksu , I just saw above you asking for a function : see below

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "null"]
def remove_null(self):
    return [x for x in self if x != "null"]
asd = remove_null(a)
print asd
```

output

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: "I have a lot of arguments. If I don't need them, I set them to "null". I have code that doesn't add "null" to the function. But, now that I use the *add (add is my argument which adds an item to the list) instead of add, it puts a couple "null"s in the output."

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are talking about @m1ksu ? could you please add some examples ?

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that you wish to convert the list to a string with a function and display each data element on a separate line without null being included.  So, here's what I suggest:

```
# remove null and convert list to string with function  
# and display results on separate lines

a = ["a", "b", "c", "null"] 

def str(A): 
    a = [data for data in A if data != "null"]
    aSTR = '\n'.join(a)
    return aSTR

print str(a)
```

Run code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRllvRExHa3pjM2M)